# Detect flexible patterns?

Tags: regex, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I need to detect a flexible pattern in a data set. For example a pattern like:

```
0{1},1{*},0{1}
(the number between { and } is how many times a number may occur)
```

This will match:

```
0,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,0
```

Above one is still easy here is a more difficult one:

```
0{1},( 1{*} | 1{*},2{1},1{*} ),0{1}
(the | pipe character is a "or")
```

This will match:

```
0,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,2,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,0
```

I'm finding it difficult to understand how i can detect these flexible patterns.

My first thought was to generate some kind of decision tree, but this becomes quite a difficult task when the patterns become even more complex, especially because you than have to go backwards in such a tree and mark paths as "not working" and try a alternative route.

Is there maybe a better solution for this kind of problem?

[edit] Oops, i might have oversimplified my question, the little numbers 0,1,2 are in my case not numbers but object with many properties. My pattern definition will match one or a combination of these object properties.

Comment: Can't you just rewrite your patterns into normal regular expressions?

Comment: @svick , i think i might have over simplified things, patterns contain things like (i>x && i<y combined with and and or's) and they go a few levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking of building a regular expression matcher. Every regular expression can be formulated as a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). Here is a link explaining [how](http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/spring01/notes/node9.html).

Comment: Thanks Pradhan, i never heard of DFA's, so i'm first going to do a bit of reading on the subject.